# Language to describe a data structure

Tags: java, thymeleaf, gherkin

I'm developing a testing tool and I want to generate an easy to read description of the test cases (in Gherkin Syntax).

Here's an example of a description I want to create (sorry for the German):

```
Gegeben Partner NP_M_IT_VN,
und Vertrag 3bRIS_T
und der Vertrag wurde bis 17.02.2022 fortgeschrieben,
wenn ich eine Prämienreduktion mit Prämie neu CHF 300.00 erfasse,
und ich Stornobekäpnfung "Nicht erfolgreich" wähle,
und ich als nächsten Schritt "Reduktion durchführen" wähle,
dann sollte in ILAS ein GeVo mit Wirksamekeitsdatum 01.02.2022 und Grund "Reduzierung" erstellt worden sein,
wenn ich die Dokumente in OMS abwarte,
dann sollten erstellt worden sein,
und in FS/CD sollte ein Beleg mit Fälligkeitsdatum 01.02.2022 und Betrag CHF 300.00 vorhanden sein.
```

Tests are stored as JSON strings. The raw data for the example above is:

```
{
  "skip": false,
  "priority": "Blocker",
  "labels": "Reduktion",
  "assignee": "***",
  "key": "***",
  "summary": "[TEST E2E Prämienreduktion] - Hybrid, Prämienreduktion, ZM monatlich, Prämienrückstand",
  "steps": [
    {
      "schema": "Partner",
      "templateId": "NP_M_IT_VN",
      "data": {
        "Crm": {
          "PartnerNatuerlich": {
            "Geburtsdatum": "1970-01-01"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "schema": "IlasVertrag",
      "templateId": "3bRIS_T",
      "data": {
        "Produkt": {
          "Antragseinreichungsdatum": "=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)",
          "Unterzeichnungsdatum": "=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)"
        },
        "Vertragsteile": {
          "Tarif1": {
            "TarifKommentar": "Tod",
            "Beginn": "=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,1),\"TT.MM.JJJJ\")"
          }
        },
        "PartnerZuordnung1": {
          "Referenz": "1"
        },
        "Beteiligungsgruppe1": {
          "PartnerNr": "21000009",
          "PartnerNr_ACC_INT": "35873466"
        },
        "Pruefung": {
          "Crm": "true"
        },
        "Verschiedenes": {
          "TestDatum": "=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,0),\"TT.MM.JJJJ\")"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "schema": "IlasFortschreibung",
      "data": {
        "Wirksamkeitstermin": "=TODAY()",
        "Pruefung": {
          "Ilas": "false",
          "FscdMinSaldo": "500.0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "schema": "BpmReduktion",
      "data": {
        "Art": "Prämienreduktion",
        "PraemieNeu": "300",
        "ArtDerAntragseinreichung": "Brief",
        "Stornobekaempfung": "Nicht erfolgreich",
        "NaechsterSchritt": "Reduktion durchführen"
      }
    },
    {
      "schema": "IlasPruefung",
      "data": {
        "Vertragsstand": {
          "WirksamekeitsDatum": "=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)",
          "Grund": "Reduzierung",
          "AnzahlPassendeVertragsstaende": "1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "schema": "OmsDokumenteAbwarten",
      "data": {
        "AnzahlAuftraege": "1",
        "Min2h": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "schema": "OmsDokumentePruefung2",
      "data": {}
    },
    {
      "schema": "FscdPruefung",
      "data": {
        "Beleg1": {
          "Faelligkeitsdatum": "=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)",
          "Betrag": "300"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For each type of test steps there is a generated Java class. My idea was to produce the description in Java. For instance, the code to describe test step 'BpmReduktion' is:

```
@Override
public void describe(GherkinData gherkin) throws Exception {
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("ich eine " + getArt());
    if (getPraemieNeu() != null) {
        sb.append(" mit Prämie neu " + formatAmount("praemieNeu"));
    }
    if (getLeistungNeu() != null) {
        sb.append(" mit Leistung neu ");
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            String tarif = (String) getLeistungNeu().getClass().getMethod("getTarif" + i).invoke(getLeistungNeu());
            if (tarif != null) {
                strings.add(formatAmount("leistungNeu.leistung" + i) + " für " + tarif);
            }
        }
        sb.append(kommaUnd(strings));
    }
    if ((getBenutzer() != null) && (getBenutzer().getGA() != null) && getBenutzer().getGA()) {
        sb.append(" als GA");
    }
    gherkin.addWhen(sb.toString() + " erfasse");
    
    gherkin.addWhen("ich Stornobekäpnfung " + quote(getStornobekaempfung()) + " wähle");

    gherkin.addWhen("ich als nächsten Schritt " + quote(getNaechsterSchritt()) + " wähle");
}
```

But I feel, with this approach I'm going to end up with a lot of arbitrary, hard to maintain Java code. I'm looking for a language where the code is closer to the description being generated, like Thymeleaf, but better suited for human readable text.

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you want to process the contents of a JSON file and convert it into a Step Definition file using Gherkin. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's wrong with writing Gherkin in the first place? I tried a similar strategy and it ended up being kind of a nightmare. The main reason is because JSON doesn't have any constraints in the contents that you want to put in it, so long the data types match. Basically, you want to build a Gherkin Compiler. To me, having gone that path before, I will discourage you from doing it unless you have a very strong reason to do it. (i.e. you have thousands of test cases in JSON format already).

Comment: The JSON data contains all the details the execute the test automatically, while the Gherkin description is supposed to be a summary to quickly understand what the test is doing. Users enter tests through an input form, and the details are stores as JSON. The input form (and the resulting JSON data) can be come quite large, as it contains all the details about the insurrance contract.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/data-driven-testing-using-json-with-cucumber/

Comment: Thanks, I will have a good look at it.

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't